# How to use Rectangle as an opacity mask

Tags: c#, wpf, image, mask

I'm trying to make a Layer Mask for black area in my image,I have an image like this:

[image]

I draw an rectangle on it:

[image]

how can i make a mask that show following image(White area 100% transparent and Black area with mask color)

[image]

Comment: Provided that the image background is transparent, not white, you may use an [ImageBrush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imagebrush.aspx) for the [OpacityMask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.opacitymask.aspx) property of the red rectangle.

Comment: @Clemens:what about white background?

Comment: Change white to transparent in some image editor.

Answer (score 0):

1. In any image editor select all white color and remove it.
2. Save image in PNG format.
3. Use it in XAML like an opacity mask.